# Where is the TTL (Time-To-Live) value defined in the Linux kernel source?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm having a hard time finding where, in the Linux Kernel source, the TTL is defined. Could someone point out which file that's in?

I'm not sure, but I may have found it at line 820 in `net/ipv4/ipconfig.c`

```
    /* Construct IP header */
    skb_reset_network_header(skb);
    h = ip_hdr(skb);
    h->version = 4;
    h->ihl = 5;
    h->tot_len = htons(sizeof(struct bootp_pkt));
    h->frag_off = htons(IP_DF);
    h->ttl = 64;
```

If I change that and compile the kernel source, would I then be using the new value?

Edit: It may also be defined in `include/uapi/linux/ip.h` at line 69:

```
#define IPVERSION   4
#define MAXTTL      255
#define IPDEFTTL    64
```

Comment: you can mangle TTL with iptables for start.

Comment: I am aware of that. However, I'm trying to learn more about Linux kernel networking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out. It IS defined in `include/uapi/linux/ip.h` at line 69 (for version 5.5-rc5).

```c
#define IPDEFTTL    64
```

I changed that to something else (i.e. 123), compiled the source, installed it, and used Wireshark to verify that my packets' TTL was changed (to 123).

The location in the source where this is used is in `net/ipv4/af_inet.c` at line 1828 (for version 5.5-rc5):

```c
    /* Default values for sysctl-controlled parameters.
     * We set them here, in case sysctl is not compiled.
     */
    net->ipv4.sysctl_ip_default_ttl = IPDEFTTL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at: '/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_default_ttl'.

More description:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/667096/how-to-change-the-default-ttl-of-tcp-ip-packets

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for where the default TTL is set in the kernel source code.